# Scroll to new content inserted

Tags: jquery

Let's say I made an insertion of a post to a database, then, I don't want to reload the page to show it, so I append it, with jQuery..now...how could I do to scroll down to that post and do like an animate to show the user that's the new post inserted. Something like Facebook, when you open a notification of a comment, it scrolls down to the comment and puts the div on yellow then deletes that class, so that the background is white again

I hope I explain myself crearly! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="content">
  // parent container where to add element
</div>

$('#content').append('<div class="newlyappend">Sample Text'+ c++ +'</div>');
$('#content').scrollTop($('#content').height());
```

**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/HCpDV/)**